# How to update values that depend on strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an action (using strong parameters) in controller:

```
def home_task_params
  params.require(:home_task).permit(:subject, :description, :data)
end
```

I want to modify the data before recording to the database. I want to do something similar to this:

```
def create
  @home_task = HomeTask.create(
    :subject => home_task_params.subject,
    :description => home_task_params.description,
    :day => home_task_params.data,
    :data => home_task_params.data,
    :class_room => current_user.class_room
  )
end
```

How do I implement it?

Comment: Did you try running the code? Any error?

Comment: undefined method `subject' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x00007f51a05379f8>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params` is an object that behaves like a hash. Therefore you cannot read values from that object like this `params.subject` instead, you have to use `params[:subject]`.

Something like this might work:

```
@home_task = HomeTask.create(
  :subject     => home_task_params[:subject], 
  :description => home_task_params[:description], 
  :day         => home_task_params[:data],
  :data        => home_task_params[:data], 
  :class_room  => current_user.class_room 
)
```

Or you could just merge the additional values to `params`:

```
@home_task = HomeTask.create(
  home_task_params.merge(
    day: home_task_params[:data], 
    class_room: current_user.class_room
  )
)
```